# Bootstrap3 Bundle for symfony2

Tags: symfony, bundle, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any Bundle for using in symfony2 that has features of Bootstrap3?

I have tried coding myself but there are issues with many components so to complete my project quickly I am searching for an already made bundle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for MopaBootstrapBundle which integrates twitter bootstrap in your Symfony2 project (form, menu...)

Github: https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle

Docs: https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Answer (score 4):

You can try http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/ also.
Works very good for me.

Answer (score 3):

As of Symfony 2.6, Bootstrap support for forms comes standard: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes

Just update your config.yml to use it:

```
# config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    form_themes:
        - bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig
```

Have fun!

Answer (score -1):

You can add the [github repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) to your composer. Add it to your `composer.json` like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "twbs/bootstrap": "master"
    }
}
```

See the [composer documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository) for more examples and explanations